# Formatting a list to print out common numbers

Tags: python-3.x, list, format, dataset

I want to write a function that goes through all 3 of the lists down below and would print out the numbers that are present on all 3. Like how the number 23 is present on all 3 lists.

```
list_1 =[27, 20, 22, 21, 17, 12, 24, 23, 19, 14, 11, 26, 25, 13, 15, 21, 18, 28, 29, 10]
list_2 = [14, 25, 26, 21, 22, 17, 11, 23, 27, 18, 24, 28, 12, 29, 16, 19, 13, 10, 20, 15]
list_3 = [19, 21, 11, 24, 16, 17, 18, 22, 26, 10, 23, 29, 27, 13, 25, 14, 15, 20, 28, 12]
```

Comment: Cast lists to sets and use intsersection.

Answer (score 0):

As @Heike said, you can use `intersect1d`

```py
print(reduce(np.intersect1d, (list_1, list_2, list_3)))
```

Result:

---

```py
[10 11 12 13 14 15 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29]
```

Code:

---

```py
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

list_1 = [27, 20, 22, 21, 17, 12, 24, 23, 19, 14, 11, 26, 25, 13, 15, 21, 18, 28, 29, 10]
list_2 = [14, 25, 26, 21, 22, 17, 11, 23, 27, 18, 24, 28, 12, 29, 16, 19, 13, 10, 20, 15]
list_3 = [19, 21, 11, 24, 16, 17, 18, 22, 26, 10, 23, 29, 27, 13, 25, 14, 15, 20, 28, 12]

print(reduce(np.intersect1d, (list_1, list_2, list_3)))
```